# How to get the contents specified in the brackets?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, pattern-matching

I want to extract the content written in a file. Let us take an example

```
{{{
      How 
      R 
      U
}}}

{{{ Hi }}}
```

I want to print the output like this

```
 How
 R
 U

 Hi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not `regex` this is using `gawk` multi-character `RS`.

```
awk -v RS='}}}|{{{' 'NF' inputfile

      How
      R
      U

 Hi
```

You can `pipe` above command with something like this `sed -r  's/^ +//g'` to remove extra spaces at the start of the line.

Comment: By default `awk` consider each line as record and `\n` as record separator( `RS`). Here we forced awk to consider record separator as `{{{` or `}}}`

Comment: Why you used pipe and what does NF does

Comment: You can try the experimenting with `piping` and without `piping`.  `NF` means number of fields, its an awk's cryptic way of saying print only lines which have any fields

Comment: Can I print hi or how r u alone

Comment: replace `NF` with `/Hi/` to print `Hi`

Comment: Thank you for instant support

Answer (score 0):

By using regular expressions this becomes tricky, mainly because `grep` or `awk` seem not to support the [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

To extract or match only the text within the curly braces this regex could be used: https://regex101.com/r/ASFIFa/1

```
[^{\}]+(?=})
```

Therefore you could give a try to the [ag - The Silver Searcher](https://geoff.greer.fm/ag/), something like this produce your required output:

```
$ ag -o '[^{\}]+(?=})' input.txt
```

To remove the leading spaces:

```
$ ag -o '[^{\}]+(?=})' input.txt | sed 's/^ *//'
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed '/{{{/!d;:A;/\}\}\}/!{N;bA};s/{{{//;s/}}}//;s/ *//g' infile
```

Or

```
sed -E '/\{{3}/!d;:A;/\}{3}/!{N;bA};s/\{{3}| *|\}{3}//g' infile
```